# Signed app won't upload on Play Store with Jenkins (Upload failed: - Forbidden) but it works if I do it manually on the Play Console

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play-console

I'm using Jenkins and the Google Play Android Publisher plugin to upload all my other apps.

I have uploaded a new app, and I was required to make a new keystore because the one I was using didn't match the security requirements.

If I build a bundle with Android Studio with that keystore and upload it, it works, but not if I upload it with Jenkins.

The only other difference beside keystore is that this app is uploaded on another company's Google account, using the same dev account as my other apps.

Here is my error message (I get this warning with my other apps too).

> Warning:  The signer's certificate is self-signed. Authenticating to
>   Google Play API...
>   - Credential:     Google Play Android Developer
>   - Application ID: com.company.myapp
>
> Upload failed: 
>   - Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

All the APKs uploaded for an app need to be signed with the same keystore. This is required because the Android platform will refuse to update an APK if it is signed with a different key.

Ensure that Jenkins references the same keystore as the one you use when building with Studio (or whichever keystore you said works).